# Форма не работает

Tags: html

Помогите пожалуйста, у меня почему-та не работает форма
вот код:

```
<form action="mailto:rproger@mail.ru" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><p class="dannie">имя<em>*</em>:</p></td>
            <td><p><input type="text" name="names"></p></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><p class="dannie">телефон<em>*</em>:</p></td>
            <td><p><input type="text" name="tel"></p></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><p class="dannie">email<em>*</em>:</p></td>
            <td><p><input type="text" name="email"></p></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><p><input type="submit" value="отправить"></p></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><p class="tab_bot">работаем круглосуточно | 7 дней в неделю</p></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: 1) Что вы ожидаете?

2) Что на самом деле выполняется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В атрибуте `action` нужно указывать не `mailto:rproger@mail.ru`, а адрес к скрипту обработчику, например: `<form action="handler.php" method="post">`

В скрипте `handler.php` уже должна быть вся логика и отправка на почту `php` функцией `mail()`

Comment: тоесть скрипт в любом случае нужен?

Comment: Ваш вариант обращается к почтовому клиенту. Пользователю будет необходимо вручную отправить письмо по адресу, указанному в форме.

Если вы хотите, чтобы письмо отправлялось сразу, то как указал mountpoint, нужно убирать логику в php.